# What's the meaning of "frequency represents area of bars" in histogram?

Tags: data-visualization, histogram, frequency, exploratory-data-analysis

In some statistics lessons, I have heard that frequency represents area of bars. So I was curious and plotted these numbers:

> [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10]

The histogram has frequency on y-axis:

[image]

This histogram is representing the height as frequency, but if I want areas then width = 2 and heights are 3, 5, 4, 4, 5. Areas would l x b =

- First bar, 3 x 2 = 6
- Second bar, 5 x 2 = 10
- Third bar, 4 x 2 = 8
- Fourth bar, 4 x 2 = 8
- Last bar, 5 x 2 = 10

I don't see these 6, 10, 8, 8, 10 numbers anywhere. So, how exactly area is represented by frequency?

Comment: The _Area_ of your first bar is computed as follows: _Relative frequency_ is 3 divided by sample size 42. _Density_ is $\frac{3}{42(2)}.$ _Area_ is Density times width (same as relative frequency). Sum of _Areas_ (relative frequencies) is 1. See my Answer for details. (The 'Frequency' label on your histogram seems confusing.)

Comment: I think most people would say that the area of the bars represents the frequency, instead of the other way around. The frequency is a "real" concept being represented by the histogram, not the other way around.

Comment: You may check [this article.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zc7sb82/revision/9#:~:text=The%20area%20of%20the%20bar%20represents%20the%20frequency%2C%20so%20to,This%20is%20called%20frequency%20density.&text=Once%20the%20frequency%20densities%20of,the%20histogram%20can%20be%20drawn.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of a 'density' histogram, for which the vertical scale is
chosen so that the total area of all of the bars in the histogram is $1.$

Below is such a density histogram from R statistical software. It is based on a dataset of size n  = 1000, generated from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma=5).$ Bin widths are 5.

```
 set.seed(2020)
 x = rnorm(1000, 50, 5)
 cutpt = seq(25,70,by=5)
 hist(x, prob=T, lab=T, br=cutpt, ylim=c(0, .1), col="skyblue")
  curve(dnorm(x, 50, 5), col="darkgreen", lwd=2, add=T)
```

[image]

The argument `lab=T` of the procedure `hist` causes 'densities' (slightly rounded) to be plotted atop
each bar. These are the heights of the bars on the density scale.
For reference, the density function of the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma=5)$ of the population from which the $n=1000$ observations were sampled, is shown
along with the histogram.

In R, output for a 'non-plotted' histogram gives some information about the
values used in constructing the histogram. (Only relevant parts of the output
are shown here.)

```
hist(x, prob=T, br=cutpt, plot=F)
$breaks
[1] 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70
$counts
[1]   0   4  23 142 355 325 119  30   2
$density
[1] 0.0000 0.0008 0.0046 0.0284 0.0710 0.0650 0.0238 0.0060 0.0004
```

The relative frequency (proportion of the whole sample) of each bar is its density times its width $5.$ These are the areas of each bar. The sum of the areas is $1.$ For example, in the $4$th bin, the *frequency* is $142,$ the *relative frequency* is $142/1000 = 0.142,$ and the *density* is $0.142/5 = 0.0284.$

```
den = hist(x, prob=T, br=cutpt, plot=F)$den
sum(5*den)
[1] 1
```

For a sample size as large as $n=1000,$ we can expect that the histogram will
roughly imitate the shape of the population density function. A kernel density
estimate (KDE) provides a way to make a curve that may match the population
more closely. The KDE uses the data directly and is not influenced by the
bins chosen to make the histogram. The area beneath the KDE is also (very nearly)
$1.$ In the figure below the KDE is plotted as a dotted red curve.

```
 set.seed(2020)
 x = rnorm(1000, 50, 5)
 cutpt = seq(25,70,by=5)
 hist(x, prob=T, br=cutpt, ylim=c(0, .1), col="skyblue")
  curve(dnorm(x, 50, 5), col="darkgreen", lwd=2, add=T)
  lines(density(x), lwd=3, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

**Addendum** per Comments.

For your data, in R:

```
x = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10)

table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 3  2  3  2  2  1  3  2  1  2
```

The following gives a 'frequency' histogram as shown. (Parameter
`labels=T` causes frequencies to be printed atop bars; parameter
`ylim=c(0,6)` makes the window large enough to show
the frequencies.) The height of each bar simply represents the
number of data points within the bin interval for each bar.

```
hist(x, br=5, ylim=c(0,6),  labels=T)
```

[image]

To emphasize that each observation is represented by "basic unit of area", I now add horizontal reference lines, not normally shown. Ths sample size
is $n=21,$ so there are 21 rectangles within the histogram bars.)

```
 hist(x, br=5, ylim=c(0,6),  labels=T)
  abline(h=1:5, col="green", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Here is a 'stripchart' (dotplot) of the data, illustrating which points
are in which histogram bins.

```
stripchart(x, meth="stack", pch=20, xlim=c(0,10), offset=.5)
 abline(v=seq(0,10,by=2)+.05, col="green", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

The following R code makes a 'density' histogram (on account of the parameter
'prob=T'). You can multiply the width (2) of each interval by its
density to get the area of each bar. The sum of these areas is $1.$

```
hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.15), labels=T)
```

[image]

Comment: I see, that was helpful as well. But my question was different I think. For example, when you plot a histogram with different bin widths, you get different areas in each bar. These areas don't represent the frequency well. Under this context, I wanted to know how frequency is area of a bar? The y-axis is labelled as 'Frequency' but it seems actually to be the height of bar. So, frequency and height should different but it appears they are not.

Comment: Unless you are trying to give a graphical description of a heavily skewed distribution, it is almost always a mistake to make a histogram with unequal bin widths. If you have a specific question about a histogram with unequal bit widths, then please formulate it clearly and post it separately.

Comment: Sure, I think I would, but in my diagram posted in the question, would say the y-axis is frequency or height of the bar? or, frequency = height? Normally, it is labeled as frequency but it seems the height.

Comment: Did you see my Comment below your Question, where I addressed this? Also, I was gently trying to say the histogram in your question is improperly labeled and badly drawn. If acceptable answers need to justify that histogram, then I think you will have a long wait for an acceptable answer.

Comment: Can you perhaps include in your answer how would you properly draw and label it from the same data? I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: The addendum to my answer shows the two style of histograms produced by by the `hist` procedure in R. I hope this clarifies my discussion of histograms.

Comment: Interesting histogram. I thought interval 0 to 2 would only include 0 and 1 values and then next interval 2 to 4 would include 2 and 3 values so on.

Comment: Good point. R has the capability to have intervals that include the right endpoint or that don't. See [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/hist), parameter `right`. In a report or publication, one should always say (in text or legend) what convention for endpoints is being followed. Sometimes which convention is preferred depends on country.   // That's why I added the stripchart to make the convention clear here.